# How to start an app with "Always On Top" set?

Tags: gnome, application-development, window-manager

There are a couple of applications that I find myself marking as "Always on Top" every time I use them, so I wonder if there is a way to automatically set them as so, whatever way I start them (menu, shell, gnome-do)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're using Compiz, you can go into CompizConfig Setting Manager, and enable the Windows Rules plugin, and then add something like `class=Gnome-terminal` under "Above" to make all Gnome Terminal windows Stick on Top. (You can click the + button and use the grab feature to figure out the class name for various applications if it's not obvious.)

### Ubuntu 16.10

Make sure to install `compiz-plugin`.

Comment: Hmpf, bah, the name of this plugin is translated totally wrong in Dutch... :-(

Comment: Very nice! I found that "sticky" is actually "always on this workspace" if anyone is wondering. Also worth mentioning is that if you are using the title of a window, i.e. title=This Window Title, you do not quote it. Use it just like I wrote it.

Comment: Am I missing something on Ubuntu 16.10 as shown by [this screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/evMkPUL.png)?

Answer (score 30):

There is a more general solution, working with a EWMH/NetWM compatible X Window Manager (all commonly used wm are included).

The solution concerns the use of the `wmctrl` application (found in `wmctrl` package).

You can set the "on-top" property with

```
wmctrl -r "window title" -b add,above
```

There is, however, some work left to automate the process.

Comment: seems like a good alternative, when compiz is  not used. nice!

Comment: This is the best option for me because I can create a bash script or a keyboard shortcut (which I did) using this command and that way I can use it when I need it but not when I don't.

I did make a change though...I wanted a shortcut to turn always on top for the active window and only when I needed so here is my command.

`wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b toggle,above`

Comment: arguments "add,above" is not working for me. but arguments "toggle, above" works (toggles).

Comment: @MichaelTunnell you should post it as answer, including setting up shortcut.

Comment: works from a shell, but it dosn't work for me inside a bash script (??...)

Answer (score 3):

There are two methods in which you can achieve this.

- This method is permanent:

  Install Compiz and then compiz-plugin. Then go into CompizConfig Setting Manager, and enable the "Windows Rules" plug-in which is in "window management". Then go to the line "Above" and press the add button in front of it, And then the "Grab" button  and then click on the window of the app which you want " always on top". Press OK.
- This method is temporary:

  Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and then <kbd>T</kbd>.

Comment: I think you mean Alt+Space. Alt+Tab is used for switching between apps