# How can I make the terminal stay on top

Tags: command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to start an app with “Always On Top” set?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7377/how-to-start-an-app-with-always-on-top-set)

Every time I use the terminal I have to right click on the title bar and click "Always on top". Is there anyway of making it do this automatically?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

right click on the top bar with "close maximize minimize" buttons and select always on top.

or

right click on the terminal tab in your panel's window list, and select always on top.

if you wan to make it permanent you have to edit the windows property in Compiz Config Setting Manager, goto Window Management click on the Window Rules option, then in the above part enter gnome-terminal.

or you can mess with metacity settings.

or you can also get CairoDock or Screenlet's terminal application and make it stay on top.