# How to set "always on top" on VLC by default?

Tags: gnome, vlc, window-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to start an app with “Always On Top” set?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7377/how-to-start-an-app-with-always-on-top-set)

I want to always run VLC with "always on top" turned on. how to set it up?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. Open VLC Media player and open *Tools -> Preferences* (keyboard shortcut - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>)
2. Open the video tab in the Preferences window
3. Check the *Always on Top* option and click save, then close it.

[image: vlc-prefs-screenshot]

Comment: I believe now the option has changed to "Float on Top" (on a mac). And also after playing, the choice has to be enabled using the menu Video -> "Float on Top"