# How to pin video player top of another app?

Tags: video-player, pinning

I am searching for a video player like "PotPlayer" in windows where i can pin the video player on top of another app, that means i can watch tutorial and code them on IDE at the same time. Is there a way to achieve this in Ubuntu? I am using Elementary Os Loki 0.4.1 which is based on Ubuntu 16.04.

Thank you.

Comment: In Ubuntu, right click the window top bar and select always on top. You might need to ask on an elementary forum.

Comment: There's a specific Stack Exchange website for Elementary: [elementaryos.se]. This question is also suitable for [unix.se] but not here because Elementary is NOT an official derivative.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the window manager options that @**hatterman** mentioned, you could use the [VLC](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/1893) feature [always on top](https://askubuntu.com/a/100240/783023).

Personally, I've good experiences with VLC, due to its configurability but mainly because I got it running on almost any OS and/or device.