# Is there an application to control which windows are on top of others?

Tags: window

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to start an app with “Always On Top” set?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7377/how-to-start-an-app-with-always-on-top-set)

Some programs (such as VLC) allow you to set them to be 'Always on top', but is there a way to do this for other programs? Perhaps there is an application that allows you to manipulate windows in this way? Or Metacity settings? There was such a thing in Windows so I'm almost certain some Linux geek has thought of it. ;)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Benett, does the linked question answer your question? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rightclick the application topbar, check off `Always on Top`

[image: Demo]

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks. So easy I didn't spot it!