# Disabling 'auto-hiding' of application windows in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04

Suppose that there is Mozilla Firefox and Sublime Text open. When I am working on a Sublime Text(smaller) window and click to resume the youtube tutorial on Mozilla Firefox, the Sublime Text window hides automatically. Is there any way to disable it?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Do you mean it is hidden behind your firefox window? Or is it that Sublime minimizes? If it's the first case, take a look at http://askubuntu.com/q/104083/58950. If you mean the auto-hide feature, follow @Olimjon recommended link in a comment to the answer, below.

Answer (score 0):

This can be cause of additional workspaces.

Check Settings->Workspaces and make its count equal 1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!The workspace count is already 1. Actually, I mean to say that it is the default behaviour. I just want that switching applications should not hide the other applications.

Comment: Then take a look at this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/25785/can-auto-hide-for-the-application-menu-be-turned-off-in-unity