# What would be the command line equivalent of "always on top" option on windows?

Tags: gnome, command-line

The question says it all really, is there a command that emulates `Always On Top` that you get by right clicking on window borders?

Comment: How would you use it exactly? `Always On Top` is a feature specifically for the GUI (windows)..

Comment: may it help :http://askubuntu.com/questions/7377/how-to-start-an-app-with-always-on-top-set

Comment: @KarthikT when the gnome-terminal starts it will execute that command on itself. - or its window even

Comment: @ZhangYuan Thanks for the link, I already checked that out earlier... Maybe this question has no answer- better off with compiz solution I guess.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Install `wmctrl`
2. Open a terminal and type `wmctrl -l`. You will see a list of windows and processes.
3. Type `wmctrl -i -r 0x01c00267 -b add,above`. Replace `0x01c00267` with the window number you want to be on top.

Comment: Instead of using `-i` for window id, we can also use a string that would match the title of the window 

`wmctrl -r erminal -b toggle,fullscreen` Instead of "Terminal", or `user@host....` we can use a partial string (I used "erminal" in the example) and `wmctrl` would try to match it. 

The first one it matches becomes the subject.