# How to change window atributtes in Wayland?

Tags: window, window-manager, wayland

I want to write an script that sets the attributes of certain windows to 'always in top'.

This [command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7377/how-to-start-an-app-with-always-on-top-set?answertab=votes#tab-top) is supposed to work on X11: `wmctrl -r "window title" -b add,above`

But it does not work on Ubuntu 21.10 running Wayland. Neither does this one `wmctrl -l` work. I found a way to list active windows in [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399753/how-to-get-a-list-of-active-windows-when-using-wayland), but still can't change the attributes.